# How JS works with its code?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does second function declaration win even though I return before it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036140/why-does-second-function-declaration-win-even-though-i-return-before-it)

I'd like to understand one thing. Does JS first go through the code to initialize variables, functions, etc. before implementing any function or output? I mean it looks like it goes through the code twice - one time to initialize and only for the second time it begins to do something. Right?

I have such code:

```
alert( (function f() {
    function f() { return 1 }

    return f();

    function f() { return 2 }
})() );
```

The output is 2. So if it begins to implement the code right from the first time, the output would be 1. But as far as output is 2 it first checks the code and only then begins to work with it. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript does "hoisting".  This basically means that any `var name` or `function name()` is hoisted to the top of whatever function body it's declared in.  So your example could be re written like this, which obeys hoisting rules.

```
var f;
f = function() {
  var f;
  f = function() { return 1; };
  f = function() { return 2; }; // hoisted!
  return f();
};
alert(f());
```

What's happening here is that in the outer scope, you make a local variable `f`.  You then assign a function to it, and then execute that function.

Inside the function, we create a new local variable `f`, which *shadows* the outer one, making it inaccessible.  We now have a totally different `f` that only exists in this inner function.  We assign the first function to it, and then the second hoisted function right after.  Now we execute our function body.

As a result, you almost never want to use the `function name() {}` syntax for creating functions because of hoisting.  Instead, use `var name = function() {}` to create functions.

It's far more controllable and understandable because declaring the variable and assigning a value to it are now 2 separate operations.  The variable declaration is still hoisted, but it won't have a value until it reaches the line of code that assigns a function to it, which is usually what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

`var` and `function` are both processed first. This is the main reason I define my functions as
`f = function()` instead of `function f()` - this way I know exactly what is defined where.

Comment: "*var and function are both processed first.*" - This should be explained in a little more detail...