# function call with arguments less than declared parameters

Tags: javascript

Why the following code ends up with the function with the most parameters get called - function foo (a, b, c)?

```
function foo (a) {
 console.log("single parameter function")
};
function foo (a, b) {
 console.log("two parameter function");
}
function foo (a, b, c) {
 console.log("three parameter function");
}
foo("hello", "goodbye");
```

Comment: change the order of declaring the functions, see what happens - or just read the answer below I guess

Comment: What happens if you have `function foo(){}` is very simple: A variable `foo` is created and is assigned a function object as value. It is not invalid to have multiple declarations with the same name, but a variable can only have a single value. The variable will be assigned the function object created by the last declaration.

Comment: Duplicate of [*Why does second function declaration win even though I return before it?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036140/why-does-second-function-declaration-win-even-though-i-return-before-it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function overloading is not a thing in Javascript. A function name can only be defined once. You don't actually have three different versions of `foo`, you have one: the last one declared.